# Getting the raw bitmap of the zxing barcode reader

Tags: android, bitmap, zxing

I've started programming an app which uses zxing to decode barcodes.
What I'd like to do is to obtain the picture (taken by zxing) of the barcode as a normal sized bitmap (or jpg) and without the green laser beam in it.
If it was possible to call it from my app directly (would be fantastic) or to change zxing code and safe it to a local folder and reopen it in my app.
I've allready checked search engines and looked through the zxing code, however, I could not locate the right file.
I'd be really appriciated it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks very much